# iptables - Port forwarding with keeping source IP

Tags: networking, server, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a Ubuntu Server with two interfaces: `enp1s0` and `ham0` (private network). In interface `ham0` my IP-address is 25.70.228.164. Another machine in this network has IP-address 25.11.1.253. I tried to set these iptables rules:

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000:9005 -j DNAT --to-destination 25.11.1.253
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 25.11.1.253 --dport 9000:9005 -j SNAT --to-source 25.70.228.164
```

It works fine, but the second machine (25.11.1.253) doesn't see real IP-addresses of incoming packages. It sees IP-addresses of the first machine (25.70.228.164).

I heard that it's possible to save source IP via setting a default gateway, but I don't understand what I should to do.

Is it even possible with iptables and what should I to do?

Comment: It can depend on what version of Ubuntu you are using. What version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to save the source IP with iptables, and such behaviour is actually the more normal method for port forwarding.

Delete this line:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 25.11.1.253 --dport 9000:9005 -j SNAT --to-source 25.70.228.164
```

Change this line:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9000:9005 -j DNAT --to-destination 25.11.1.253
```

To this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i enp1s0 --dport 9000:9005 -j DNAT --to-destination 25.11.1.253
```

If the IP address of `enp1s0` is known and static ($EXTIP), add this line:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j SNAT --to $EXTIP
```

If the IP address of `enp1s0` is not known, maybe dynamic, add this line:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This answer assumes the default policy for the FORWARD chain is ACCEPT. A default policy of DROP might be more secure, which would require these additional rules (untested):

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i ham0 -o enp1s0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o ham0 -p tcp --dport 9000:9005 -d 25.11.1.253 -j ACCEPT
```

You also need to enable forwarding (which I think you did, but for completeness):

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: doesn't work for me at all. The second machine doesn't receive any packages. I also tried to change `iptables -P FORWARD DROP` to `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Comment: What is the netmask for your ham0 sub-net? I ask because the two addresses involved are so different. I assumed the packets that get forwarded arrive on the enp1s0 nic, is that true?